# R - "Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : cannot open the connection"

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of this form:

```html
X1                                      X2 X3                       X4
R290601 WOVEN TWILL                    001  6                      231
009-1373  *with perforated L3-0,3      152 NA                     <NA>
R481400 THREAD                       A1282 12                    A0399
0091375 PURE SOCK                      001  6                      072
R282380 SOFTLIN W/FELT                 007  6                      072
R282480 MICROFIBRE                     001  6                      F72
R281200 ARTIFICIAL                   A0638  6                      072
```

I want to loop through the rows, for every row check the name of the 1st column (X1) & create a folder in my computer that will have the same name and inside this folder, create sub folders that will have the same names as their respective columns (X2), (X3), (X4). When I run the script, I can only see folder **R290601 WOVEN TWILL** is created, with sub folders **001**, **6** and **231**, but not the rest, and I get this error :

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
>     cannot open the connection

Additionally, I get this warning for the 2nd row :

> In dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X1[i])) :
>     cannot create dir 'C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Joe\009-1373  *with perforated L3-0,3', reason 'Invalid argument'

My code is this:

```html
getwd()
setwd("C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/Joe")

library(xlsx)
library(rJava)
library(xlsxjars)

#get file names
f = list.files("./")
#read files
dat = lapply(f, function(i){
  x = read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1, sheetName = NULL, startRow = 24,
                endRow = NULL, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = FALSE)
  #return columns with names and colors
  x = x[, c(1, 2, 3, 4), drop=FALSE] 
  #return the data
  x
})

library(plyr)
df1 <- ldply(dat, data.frame) ## convert list into a dataframe

#remove NA's
complete.cases(df1)
x <- df1[complete.cases(df1),]
str(x)

#show only rows that start with numbers or 1 letter and then numbers
df <-df1[grepl("^[0-9]|^[a-zA-Z][0-9].*", df1$X1), ]
print(df)

pth <- "C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/Joe/"

# Iterate within each row of df
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  # Create 1st path
  dir.create(paste0(pth , df$X1[i]))
  # Create 2nd and 3rd paths
  dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X1[i], "/",df$X2[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X1[i], "/",df$X3[i]))
  dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X1[i], "/",df$X4[i]))
 
  # write data.frame row as txt
  write.table(df[i, ], file=paste0(pth, df$X1[i], "/", df$X1[i],".txt"), sep=";")
}
```

Why do I get this error and how could I see all the folders with their corresponding sub folders?

Comment: the problem might be that some symbols are not allowed in path/file names. Thus you might use a `?gsub` on the column `X1` first, in order to substitute them with symbols like "_"

Comment: It's true, I tried `df1$X1 <- gsub("[[:punct:]]","-",df1$X1)` and now I can see all the folders with their sub folders, but the error is still there. Why is that?

Comment: Also I get these warnings now : **In dir.create(paste0(pth, df$X1[i], "/", df$X11[i])) : 'C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Joe\091-1958 SAMBAL 1-3-1-5mm\NA' already exists**. What can I do to avoid that and how can I remove the NA sub folders?

Comment: obviously you have some NAs in your column X11. Thus you create dir .../NA. You can remove the lines with `df1 <- df1[!is.na(df1$X11),]`

Comment: That was another question I have. Since I use `complete.cases(df1)` , why do I still get NA's?

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem, and I realized it was because I had the .csv files that it called for open in Excel. Closing the files solved the problem.

Comment: Not just Excel. It also happens if you have called `View(df)` in RStudio and you have not closed the tab before trying to write the `df` to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
## First read the dataframe taht contains Folder & Sub-folder names
df <- read_excel("C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/Joe/df.xlsx") 


## Special characters like "\ / : * ? " < > |" cann't be present in filename,
## So first remove it from the df for every column.
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), .fns = function(x) gsub('[[:punct:]]','', x))) ## '[[:punct:]]' for the special character


setwd('C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/Joe') ## Replace with your working directory



for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  
  df_name <- df[i, ] %>% 
    select_if(~ !is.na(.x)) %>% 
    select_if(~ .x != 'NA') ## if NA is character & you don't need it
  
  for(j in 1:ncol(df_name)){
    
    if(!is.na(df_name[,j])){
      if(!dir.exists(as.character(df_name[,j]))){
        dir.create(as.character(df_name[,j]), recursive = TRUE)
        setwd(as.character(df_name[,j])) ## Set wd to the newly created dir
        ## X1 --> X2 --> X3 --> X4
      }
    }
    
  }
  
  setwd('C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/Joe') ## Again go back to the main wd

}

## IF you want the folder like this : X1 --> X2, X3, X4 then 

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  
  df_name <- df[i, ] %>% 
    select_if(~ !is.na(.x)) %>% 
    select_if(~ .x != 'NA') ## if NA is character & you don't need it
  
  if(!is.na(df_name[,1])){
    if(!dir.exists(as.character(df_name[,1]))){
      dir.create(as.character(df_name[,1]), recursive = TRUE)
      setwd(as.character(df_name[,1])) ## Set wd to the newly created dir
    }
  }
  
  for(j in 2:ncol(df_name)){
    
    if(!is.na(df_name[,j])){
      if(!dir.exists(as.character(df_name[,j]))){
        dir.create(as.character(df_name[,j]), recursive = TRUE)
      }
    }
    
  }
  
  setwd('C:/Users/Dev/Desktop/Joe') ## Again go back to the main wd
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I corrected it by creating an excel file with the same first column as the data (that I can't extract in csv).  The data that I can't extract in csv I call here dataA, and the excel file (.xl) I call here dataB.
So, in dataB there is the same first column as in dataA.
I import the dataB:

```
dataB <- read_excel(".....")
```

I just import columns one by one from dataA to dataB:

```
dataB$Secondcolumn <- dataA$Secondcolumn

dataB$Thirdcolumn <- dataA$Thirdcolumn
```

.
.
.
And then:

```
write.csv(dataB, "dataB")
```